# Set spinner title when activity is created

Tags: android

I have a spinner whose elements set by an arrayList.this arraylist gets data by calling an api. I have set title at 0th position of  arrayList .the problem is i want to show this title as activity is created. but this will set only when api calling is successful .it takes some time to load data. can anyone give me better idea to set title to spinner.

Answer (score 0):

If data comes from api then you can add dialog on screen and hide title until api call success.. when you get response true then show titleview and add title from api. and api response is false then show error.. so user will get better view..

Thanks

Comment: I know this thing ....i have two spinners in my activity.t The second spinner couldn't  get data untill first spinner set a value. because for second spinner the api url gets id from first spinner selected value. So i strongly need a method to set default title.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
 R.layout.spinner_item, CatagoryName);

    // create a spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // add adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    // create listener and add to spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
       position, long id) {
              // put code which recognize a selected element
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this way

```
ArrayList<String> list  = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(0,"Please Select");

        ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CatagoryName); 
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

        // now call the API for data 

        //After data received, you have to make  temp list to store response
        ArrayList<String> Templist  = new ArrayList<>();

        //Templist = Server response

        //now add templist in main List
        list.addAll(Templist);
        // and call this
        stringArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```